# Why is 32-bit called as x86 and not as x32 in operating system architectures?

Tags: operating-system, 64-bit, 32-bit

Why is 32-bit called x86 system and not x32? As an example, Windows uses x86 in System Drive instead of using 32bit. Is there a hidden fact behind that.I'm fascinated to get the answer from the community.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is Windows 32-bit called Windows x86 and not Windows x32?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29974425/why-is-windows-32-bit-called-windows-x86-and-not-windows-x32)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it has nothing to do with that :).

They are called x86 because it was based on the 8086 microprocessor made by Intel. This became x86 because a lot of their processors end with 86.

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86)